# AWS Readshift: Reat text field with size over 65535

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I'm reading data from a table using federated query, and one of the fields of this table stores a text in JSON format.

I'm using Redshift to extract data from the JSON field and store it into several tables inside Redshift. But some of those JSONs have a size over 65535, and Redshift triggers an error while reading this field.

Is there any work around for this situation, any way to increase this size limit or on doing Redshift reading the field as something else (not as varchar)?

Comment: A Super data type can store 1M per field.  Can you access this data as a super?